# How can I send a disconnect message to websocket before leaving page

Tags: javascript, websocket, onunload

So basically, if I have say a chat application using websockets, I want to be able to send the server a message saying I'm disconnecting.  I've tried binding to onbeforeunload, but that seems to only be able to display a message.

Is there a better strategy to this?  If not, it seems like I'd have to do some sort of ping/timeout strategy from the server side.

Thanks.

Comment: Broken connections will always happen; IMO you will *always* need some sort of ping/timeout strategy. The inbuilt ping doesn't work on all browsers, so we do it by periodically sending a small message *from server to client*, and then checking whether we hear back from the client promptly.

Comment: Your server should automatically find out that connection was closed uncleanly and then you just need onClose event in your client code.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets are implemented on top of TCP, and in TCP world different connection drops - is expected scenario.

In terms of network security - your server side should never rely on "kindness" of clients, and should always be independent and expect any and more scenario of disconnects.

Taking this in account, you have to expect unexpectedly dropped connections (GPRS/EDGE/3G/4G poor connection or going under bridge/ground, wifi drops, ethernet unplug, ISP issues, server network problems, and many more). Dropped connections without "bye" in fact is most common disconnects you will get, so have to implement server side logic taking this in account.